# PHP str_replace tag

Tags: php

I have a string in PHP with some character that I want to change:
For example this a piece of string:

```
$string = '***ROOMS*** The rooms and bathrooms were fully renovated in 2006. They are reported to be quite small but are very clean, well maintained and with modern bathrooms. Rooms are tastefully designed with warm colours and pine wooden furniture. ***RESTAURANTS & BARS*** There is no restaurant in the hotel however there the comfortable ground floor lounge is open all day where ';
```

I'd want to print this paragraph like this:

```
<b>ROOMS</b><br>
 The rooms and bathrooms were fully renovated in 2006. They are reported to be quite small but are very clean, well maintained and with modern bathrooms. Rooms are tastefully designed with warm colours and pine wooden furniture.<br>
<b>RESTAURANTS & BARS</b><br> 
There is no restaurant in the hotel however there the comfortable ground floor lounge is open all day where
```

This means that the string between `***` and `***` become: `<br><b> string </b><br>`

Does exist a way with str_replace or a patter to do that?

Thanks

Comment: In this precise case, the starred parts seem to be semantically equivalent to sub-titles in your page, so they would most likely map to <h2> tags, or lower. I know this does not reply to the question specifically, but I would personnally investigate languages such as Markdown that would translate easy-to-edit text into HTML.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this :

```
$string = '***ROOMS*** The rooms and bathrooms were fully renovated in 2006. They are reported to be quite small but are very clean, well maintained and with modern bathrooms. Rooms are tastefully designed with warm colours and pine wooden furniture. ***RESTAURANTS & BARS*** There is no restaurant in the hotel however there the comfortable ground floor lounge is open all day where ';
echo preg_replace("/\*\*\*([A-Za-z\& ]*)\*\*\*/", '<br><b>$1</b><br>', $string);
```

Update : `echo preg_replace("/\*{3}([^*]*)\*{3}/", '<br><b>$1</b><br>', $string);`

Comment: Updated the answer please check it

Comment: That's not going to work correctly - it will match the first three `***` around rooms, and the last three `***` around restaurants and bars and wrap those in the `b` and `br` tags.

Comment: @RichardParnaby-King : It checks for the character inside the [] so it will work

Comment: Yeah, you updated your answer before I finished writing my comment.

Answer (score 3):

```
preg_replace("/\*{3}(.*)\*{3}/Usi", "<br><b>\\1</b><br>", $text);
```

Answer (score 2):

You will need to use regular expressions to accomplish this.

Something like:

`$newString = preg_replace('/\*\*\*([^*]+)\*\*\*/','<br/><b>$1</b><br/>',$string);`

This will capture all content between a pair of `***`.

Answer (score 0):

```
function doReplace($string)
    {
        //You can add to the following array
        //for multiple items to find within
        //the string
        $find    = array('/\*\*\*(.*?)\*\*\*/',
                         '/\*(.*?)\*/');

        //Set the replacement for each item above.
        //Make sure all the replacements are in the
        //same order for the items your finding.
        $replace = array('<b>$1</b>',
                         '<i>$1</i>');

        //Finally, do the replacement.
        return preg_replace($find, $replace, $string);
    }

    $string = '***ROOMS*** The *rooms* and bathrooms were fully renovated in 2006. They are reported to be quite small but are very clean, well maintained and with modern bathrooms. Rooms are tastefully designed with warm colours and pine wooden furniture. ***RESTAURANTS & BARS*** There is no restaurant in the hotel however there the comfortable ground floor lounge is open all day where ';

    echo doReplace($string);
```

If you ever decided to multiple replacements, the above function would work out for you, simply add to it to do such thing.